# VirtualHost adds extra url

Tags: apache-http-server, centos

So I have two domains: `site1.com` and `site2.com`. I pointed `site1.com` normally to my ip and it works, the directory is `/var/www/html`
but I can't get `site2.com` to work with `/var/www/site2`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:80
ServerName SERVERIP
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

So when enter to **site2.com/a** it automatically redirects me to **site2.com/site2/a/** which gives me error 404 and it should give it because there is no any folder named **/var/www/site2/site2/a** in my server

But if I write **site2.com/a/** it opens perfectly

And problem doesn't occur with **www.site2.com/a** or **www.site2.com/a/**.

Both of them redirects me to **www.site2.com/a/** which is correct.